# how to import / require standard node modules in typescript?

Tags: import, typescript, require

What is the best way to use `require` with typescript and standard NPM modules?
I'm trying to use the `debug` package.
I have installed from npm
also `tsd install debug`

However, Identical syntax is OK in one file, but not in another.
I guess this is a load order thing, and TS thinks I am redeclaring a variable?

```
let debug = require("debug")("async-test");
# ReferenceError: debug is not defined

debug = require("debug")("async-test");
# ReferenceError: debug is not defined
```

identical code on left/right panels (different files) will show an error/not.

[image]

Comment: Try `import * as debug from "debug";` and then `const test = debug("async-test");` Does that still give you the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the best way to use require with typescript and standard NPM modules?

Give `typings` a go. It has great `debug` definitions https://github.com/typed-typings/npm-debug.

```
npm install typings -g
typings install debug
```

Then setup your `tsconfig.json`: https://github.com/typings/typings#maindts-and-browserdts

Now you can just do:

```
import debug = require('debug')
```

With complete type safety

Comment: I'm having this problem but the error is `TS2307: Cannot find module 'debug'` ... this is with TypeScript 2.0 and the typings are in place. Any idea why I'd get this message?